# How to set different colors for each characters written in edittext in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying make characters written in `edittext` colored with a different color.
For example, I want to have 'a' in red all the time when it is written in `edittext`, while the others stay in black. Is it possible at least?

I found some answers regarding color-setting in `edittext` as below, however it is all about color-setting by the range of start index and end index.

** example **

```
final String text = "for example";
Spannable modifiedText = new SpannableString(text);
modifiedText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)), 0, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(modifiedText);
```

Comment: Yes it is the good way to use the spannable for coloring inside textview, to get index you need to use method to get the index for 'a'

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, what I am looking for is the way to take the color depends on a particular character so that whenever 'a' is typed it turns to red.  for instance, there are only three letters in red in the following example beyond their indexs.  ex) "I have an apple."

Comment: @lifeBalkan simply make a `Map<Character, Integer>`, where the character is the key and the integer is the color. Use a `TextWatcher` and whenever text is added (or replaced), add `ForegroundColorSpan`s to the new text appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible, but I don't know if is too expensive in terms of performance.
You can use a TextWatcher to color you last char inserted base on your Map of char-color.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SpannableStringBuilder mSpannableStringBuilder;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private static final Map<String, Integer> COLORS_MAP = new HashMap<>();

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // here you can populate your map with colors
        COLORS_MAP.put("a", Color.RED);
        COLORS_MAP.put("b", Color.GREEN);
        COLORS_MAP.put("c", Color.BLUE);
        COLORS_MAP.put("d", Color.MAGENTA);

        mSpannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (s.length() > 0) {

                    // unregister and register the listener to avoid infinite loop
                    mEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                    int start = s.length() - 1;
                    String lastChar = s.toString().substring(start);

                    SpannableString lastSpannableChar = new SpannableString(lastChar);

                    // pick the color based on the last char
                    int color = pickColorByChar(lastChar);

                    // Span to set char color
                    ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(color);

                    // Set the text color for the last character
                    lastSpannableChar.setSpan(fcs, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

                    // append the last char to the string builder so you can keep the previous span
                    mSpannableStringBuilder.append(lastSpannableChar);

                    mEditText.setText(mSpannableStringBuilder);
                    mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length()); //this is to move the cursor position

                    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public int pickColorByChar(String aChar){
        return COLORS_MAP.get(aChar);
    }
}
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: Do I need to add something in " // TODO get the last char and change the color based on you set char-color" ? because it dose not work with above codes only.

Comment: I updated my answer with more code. Now the example should be what you asked ;)

Comment: Yes it is! thanks a lot for the kind advise and demonstration!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `Html.fromHtml(String)` and set the font colors through that using a `Map` to your predefined colors. e.g.

```
private static final String FONT_REPLACEMENT = "<font color='%1$s'>%2$s</font>";
private static final String DEFAULT_COLOR = "#FAFAFA";

public Spanned convertToHtml(String text, Map<String, String> colorSets){
    String altered = "<![CDATA[";

    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        String value = String.valueOf(text.charAt(i));
        String color = colorSets.get(value.toLowerCase(Locale.US));

        if(color == null)
            color = DEFAULT_COLOR;

        altered += String.format(FONT_REPLACEMENT, color, value);
    }

    return Html.fromHtml(altered + "]]>");
}
```

And then to use it, you could do something like:

```
Map<String, String> colors = new HashMap<String, String();
colors.put("a", "#FF0000");
colors.put("b", "#00FF00");
colors.put("c", "#0000FF");
....

textView.setText(convertToHtml("for example", colors));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. I want those to be changed in recyclerview. So, added above codes in bindView hold method.   ** public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {Map<String, String> colors = new HashMap<String, String>();
        colors.put("*", "#ffffff");
         viewHolder.pwInput.setText(convertToHtml(myDatasetCopy.get(position).getPwInput(), colors));  ......}

Comment: and had the 'convertToHtml' method in the same class as above (in the Adapter).  **  private static final String FONT_REPLACEMENT = "<font color='%1$s'>%2$s</font>";
    private static final String DEFAULT_COLOR = "#000000";
    public Spanned convertToHtml(String text, Map<String, String> colorSets){
      }

Comment: String altered = "<![CDATA[";
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            String value = String.valueOf(text.charAt(i));
            String color = colorSets.get(value.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
            if(color == null)
                color = DEFAULT_COLOR;
            altered += String.format(FONT_REPLACEMENT, color, value);
        }
        return Html.fromHtml(altered + "]]>");  **   what i got here is '<font color='#00000.....' in my main ui. did I miss stg to change?

Comment: It's pretty difficult to diagnose the issue in these comments, but if the font color is defaulting, it's likely the colors weren't added to the map correctly. Each letter needs to have a defined color or it will default to the DEFAULT_COLOR or whatever you've chosen to change that to in the convertToHtml() method I posted above. `colors.put("*", "#ffffff"); ` would not change all of them, that would only specifically change the color of the * character to #FFF