# How to move the word cursor to a y position on the Android EditText text?

Tags: android

I want to move the cursor to a position on the text and highlight the text.
eg: I have the text "this new message"
-I want to move the cursor to the front of new and highlight black.

-EditText Android.

Answer (score 2):

EditText has a setSelection method:

```
public void setSelection (int start, int stop)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText#setSelection(int,%2520int)

Comment: But it did not color.

Comment: @DonlyConan see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20639594/9681220

Comment: I want to color the selected text then how?

Comment: @DonlyConan see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38643126/9681220